# Set "text content" in CSS when user is holding mouse on a price plan

Tags: html, css

I have created a price plan with CSS and HTML with an overlay effect. Now, I want to add a text content when a user hover one of the plans and it should say "Choose this plan." I have tried adding a "content" variable on `.green:after` and it works, but I can't figure out how to align it to the very middle.

How should i proceed?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wabMgo

Comment: So, you need to align your `content` in `.green:after` like other text?

Comment: See example on iStockphoto, monthly plans, @AleshaOleg. http://www.istockphoto.com/plans-and-pricing

Comment: Please post your code in the question.

Comment: @Utkanos http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wabMgo you can see it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to your `.green:after` - `text-align: center` to align text horizontally and `padding-top` to make inside margin in your block.

For example:

```
.overlay:after {
  position: absolute;
  content:"Money";
  top:0;
  left:0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 65px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: Excellent:) Thank you.

Comment: @kanarifugl glad to help!